# how to extract predicted survival probability for cox lasso by glmnet package?

Tags: r, lasso

I want to extract predicted survival probability in Specified times for cox lasso by glmnet package. could somebody help me?
r codes:

```
library(glmnet)
library(survival)
library(Hmisc)
data(colon)
d <- colon
head(d)
x <- model.matrix( ~ rx + sex + age + obstruct + perfor + adhere + surg - 1, d)
y <- Surv(d$time, d$status)
cv.fit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, family="cox", alpha=1)
fit=glmnet(x,y,family="cox", alpha=1)
plot(cv.fit, main="plot of fit1")
cv.fit$lambda.min
Coefficients <- coef(fit, s = cv.fit$lambda.min)
```

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.